# Go Gin setup for HTTPS on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, https, go-gin

I have a go gin server with my API that runs in an elastic beanstalk environment. I setup my API routes over HTTPS with a self-signed certificate like this:

```
    certFile := "server.crt"
    keyFile := "server.key"

    // Start the HTTPS server
    err := router.RunTLS(":8000", certFile, keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start the server: %v", err)
    }
```

This works fine. But now I want to use a certificate that is issued by AWS. I requested a cretificate in AWS certificate manager and selected that for the ssl certificate when setting up the listener for https on the Load Balancer. How can I adapt my gin server to use this certificate? Do I need to get a certificate from a different issuer?